# Output power of HEMT

Tags: power, power-electronics, power-amplifier

Reading a paper regarding a power amplifier based on HEMT technology, the following statement in made:

> 'The circuit was designed in WIN 0.1 μm GaAs process on a 2 mil thick
> substrate,has power density of **850 mW/mm** and its breakdown voltage
> 9V. According the process power density, a 4×25 μm device should
> generate a saturation power of 85mW (19.3 dBm), so aiming for 0.5 W
> (27 dBm) requires a combination of 8 devices.'

I don't understand how from the given power density and dimensions (which I suppose to be 'channel lenght x channel width' of the transistor), the saturation power ( 85mW ) is found.

Thanks to who can give me a hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

25 μm is the channel width, but 4 is not a 4-micron channel length. The phrase `4×25 μm` ostensibly refers to four "fingers" of an interdigitated device(1), having a total effective channel width of 100 μm. Of course, since that's one-tenth of 1 mm, the power density and saturation power are consistent with each other now.

(1) - an interdigitated device is one where the structure is "folded", e.g. the following **simplified** structure with two effective fingers:

[image]